# How can i make a thumbnail automatically in my Django models.py?

Tags: django-models

I'm trying to make a thumbnail automatically if there's not an existing one inside my models.py, the method resizes the image when I upload the file manually in the admin dashboard but not if the user tried to make a new post here's my models.py:

Error: "cannot write mode rgba as jpeg"

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug    =   models.SlugField()
    description =   models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=455)
    price   =   models.IntegerField()
    image   =   models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail   =   models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date_added',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return  f'/{self.category.slug}/{self.slug}/'
    
    def get_image(self):
        if self.image:
            return 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' + self.image.url
        return ''

    def get_thumbnail(self):
        if self.thumbnail:
            return 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' + self.thumbnail.url
        else:
            if self.image:
                self.thumbnail = self.make_thumbnail(self.image)
                self.save()

                return 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' + self.thumbnail.url
            else:
                return ''
    
    def make_thumbnail(self, image, size=(300, 200)):
        img = Image.open(image)
        img.convert('RGB')
        img.thumbnail(size)

        thumb_io = BytesIO()
        img.save(thumb_io, 'JPEG', quality=85)

        thumbnail = File(thumb_io, name=image.name)

        return thumbnail
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try change JPEG to PNG and try again

```
def make_thumbnail(self, image, size=(300, 200)):
     img = Image.open(image)
     img.convert('RGB')
     img.thumbnail(size)
    
     thumb_io = BytesIO()
     img.save(thumb_io, 'PNG', quality=85)
    
     thumbnail = File(thumb_io, name=image.name)
     return thumbnail
```